# Openlayers 3 get Layer extent

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm trying to change the map extent to match the wms layer extent using OpenLayers 3.0 
I found a example but doesn't work for me, not sure if is outdated

```
var extent = yourlayer.getSource().getExtent();
map.getView().fitExtent(extent, map.getSize());
```

> console.log( 'Layer:' + yourlayer.getSource() ) 
>   return  Layer: [object Object]

BUT

> console.log( 'Layer:' + yourlayer.getSource().getExtent() ) 
>   return  Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

The documentation say Layer have getExtend() method, but that doesn't work neither.

> console.log( 'Layer:' + yourlayer.getExtent() ) 
>   return  Layer: undefined

Answer (score 3):

Ensure the layer has an extent set and use,

```
var extent = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
```

Instead of,

```
var extent = yourlayer.getSource().getExtent();
```

Comment: If you see last box i try `console.log( 'Layer:' + yourlayer.getExtent() ) ` but didn't work for me

Comment: Have you defined your layer as a global constant. Otherwise you will have to use map.getLayers.getArray()[layerPosistionInArray].getExtent()

Comment: var extent = yourlayer.getExtent(); It is not working. (i'm using Openlayers 3.17). Giving error that  yourlayer.getExtent() is not a function.. Please help me..